# Closure compiler: rename object key but still able to use original key in other script

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

This code will rename object keys and still able to call functions with original key

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

var myClass = function() {
  this["myFunc"] = this.myFunc;
  this["myFunc2"] = this.myFunc2;
};
window["myClass"] = myClass;

myClass.prototype = {
  myFunc: function() { alert("myFunc"); },
  myFunc2: function() { alert("myFunc2"); }
};
```

compiled into

```
function a(){
    this.myFunc=this.a;
    this.myFunc2=this.b
}
window.myClass=a;
a.prototype={
    a:function(){alert("myFunc")},
    b:function(){alert("myFunc2")}
};
```

`(new myClass()).myFunc()` or `(new a()).a()` both work

However this method need to declare `myFunc1`,`myFunc2`...`myFuncN` too many time

Is it other way can achieve the same thing too?

I want to get this work with closure compiler to rename all `myFunc` into `a` (something like this)

In same script call `myClass.myFunc()` will compile into `a.b()`

But I still can call `window.myClass.myFunc()` in other scripts

Many thanks.

Comment: you'll want a `new a; // a {myFunc: function, myFunc2: function, a: function, b: function}`

Comment: Put quotes around `myFunc`, `myFunc2` when you declare them on prototype and cc will not rename them and you may want to jsdoc expose the methods

Answer (score 0):

`(new myClass()).myFunc()` should work :)

Anyway, you could also export your methods this way:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

var myClass = function() {
   //don't declare your exports here
};

myClass.prototype["myFunc"] = function() { alert("myFunc"); };
myClass.prototype["myFunc2"] = function() { alert("myFunc2"); };

window['myClass'] = myClass;
```

This is a bit less error prone, since you don't have to remember to "initialize" all the method names.
It compiles to:

```
function a() {
}
a.prototype.myFunc = function() {
  alert("myFunc");
};
a.prototype.myFunc2 = function() {
  alert("myFunc2");
};
window.myClass = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access them on other scripts using `window.myClass.myFunc`

This suggests you want to set the property on `window` differently, i.e. the result of a `new`, for example

```
window.myClass = (function () { // make a closure with IIFE
    function a() {
        // if all you want is on the prototype, nothing to do here
    }
    a.prototype = { // set prototype
        myFunc: function () {alert("myFunc")},
        myFunc2: function () {alert("myFunc2")}
    };
    return new a(); // construct, return out of IIFE
}()); // Invoke IIFE
```

Now, `window.myClass` is a constructed *Object* with a prototype, and you can use

```
window.myClass.myFunc(); // alerts "myFunc"
```

---

If prototyping/inheritance is not important to you, you could simply do

```
window.myClass = { // set directly
    myFunc: function () {alert("myFunc")},
    myFunc2: function () {alert("myFunc2")}
};
```

---

If prototyping/inheritance is important to you but you don't need to construct **and** can assume a modern browser,

```
window.myClass = Object.create(
    { // prototype
        myFunc: function () {alert("myFunc")},
        myFunc2: function () {alert("myFunc2")}
    }
);
```

Comment: how can i get this work with closure compiler to rename all `myFunc` into `a`, but i still able to call `window.myClass.myFunc()` in other scripts?

Comment: Did you try this code? `window.myClass` is set even after closure compiler compiles it

Comment: your code will return `window.a.b()` after compile, I can use it in the same script but can't call `window.myClass.myFunc()` from other scripts.